# Redundant/Better Performance Code VS Optimized/Less Performance Code

Tags: c#, java, performance, compiler-construction

In my case, I'm using C#, but the concept of the question would apply to Java as well. Hopefully the answer would be generic enough to cover both languages. Otherwise it's better to split the question into two.

I've always thought of which one is a better practice.

Does the compiler take care of enhancing the 'second' code so its performance would be as good as the 'first' code?

Could it be worked around to get a 'better performance' **and** 'optimized' code at the same time?

**Redundant/Better Performance Code:**

```
string name = GetName(); // returned string could be empty
List<string> myListOfStrings = GetListOfStrings();
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)
{
    foreach(string s in myListOfStrings)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}
else
{
    foreach(string s in myListOfStrings)
        Console.WriteLine(s + " (Name is: " + name);
}
```

**Optimized/Less Performance Code:**

```
string name = GetName(); // returned string could be empty
List<string> myListOfStrings = GetListOfStrings();

foreach(string s in myListOfStrings)
    Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) ? s : s + " (Name is: " + name);
```

Obviously the execution time of the 'first' code is less because it executes the condition 'string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)' only once per loop. Whereas the 'second' code (which is nicer) executes the condition on every iteration.

Please consider a long loop execution time not a short one because I know that when it is short, the performance won't differ.

Comment: There are many levels where optimization take place. For instance, your second example will benefit from branch prediction by the processor. Go for most clear, readable and maintainable. Worry about optimization when you actually have to.

Comment: I'd expect the cost of `Console.WriteLine` to dominate over the cost of the concatenation...

Comment: It's not about concatenation or Console.WriteLine. Please review the last part of the question.

Comment: Console.WriteLine intends only to clarify the question.

Comment: May be asking one more level of question give some clarity, how many milliseconds you will save with these alternate options and what if the gain is negligible?

Comment: consider a 1 million iteration x the cost of 'if' statement

Comment: @yazanpro: I would bench mark before worrying too much based on theory.

Comment: @yazanpro Go ahead and actually run it.  Checking if a string is null one million times is something that a computer can do *very* easily/quickly.  If you want to make it something to be concerned about then have the `if` check be something that requires hitting a service or database to determine.  Then it's something you don't want to be doing in a loop, even if it's only 5 iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the compiler take care of enhancing the 'second' code so its performance would be as good as the 'first' code?

No, it cannot.

1. It doesn't know that the boolean expression will not change between iterations of the loop.  It's *possible* for the code to not return the same value each time, so it is forced to perform the check in each iteration.
2. It's also possible that the boolean expression could have side effects.  In this case it doesn't, but there's no way for the compiler to know that.  It's important that such side effects would be performed in order to meet the specs, so it needs to execute the check in each iteration.

So, the next question you need to ask is, in a case such as this, is it *important* to perform the optimization that you've mentioned?  In any situation I can imagine for the exact code you showed, probably not.  The check is simply going to be so fast that it's almost certainly not going to be a bottleneck.  If there are performance problems there are almost certainly bigger fish.

That said, with only a few changes to the example it can be made to matter.  If the boolean expression itself is computationally expensive (i.e. it is the result of a database call, a web service call, some expensive CPU computation, etc.) then it could be a performance optimization that matters.  Another case to consider is what would happen if the boolean expression had side effects.  What if it was a `MoveNext` call on an `IEnumerator`?  If it was important that it only be executed exactly once because you don't want the side effects to happen N times then that makes this a *very* important issue.

There are several possible solutions in such a case.

The easiest is most likely to just compute the boolean expression once and then store it in a variable:

```
bool someValue = ComputeComplexBooleanValue();
foreach(var item in collection)
{
    if(someValue)
        doStuff(item);
    else
        doOtherStuff(item);
}
```

If you want to execute the boolean value 0-1 times (i.e. avoid calling it even once in the event that the collection is empty) then we can use `Lazy` to lazily compute the value, but ensure it's still only computed at most one time:

```
var someValue = new Lazy<bool>(() => ComputeComplexBooleanValue());
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    if (someValue.Value)
        doStuff(item);
    else
        doOtherStuff(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always go the way that is easier to understand and maintain first. This means reducing duplicate code to absolute minumum ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)). In addition this kind of micro optimization is not that important for many systems. Also note that shorter code is not always better.

I think I would go with somehting like this:

```
string name = GetName(); // returned string could be empty
bool nameIsEmpty = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name);

foreach (string s in GetListOfStrings()) {       

    string messageAddition = "";
    if (!nameIsEmpty) {
        messageAddition = " (Name is: " + name + ")";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(s + messageAddition);

    // more code which uses the computed value.. 
    // otherwise the condition can be moved out the loop
}
```

I find an extra `if` statement easier to read than the `?:` operator within a method call but this might be a personal taste.

If you want to improve performance later you should profile your application and start optimizing the slowest sections of code first. Maybe your `GetListOfStrings()` method is so slow that the performance of the other code is totally irrelevant. If you **measured** that duplicating the loop improves the perfomance by a significant value you can think about changing it.

Comment: You are considering the solution depending on the specific example proposed (concatenation). Whereas in the generic case, a whole new statement could be added after Console.WriteLine which you can't maintain beforehand.

Comment: In this case you should move the `if` block inside the loop

Comment: @micha But the boolean expression is then evaluated each iteration of the loop, despite the fact that it won't change between iterations.  That's wasted effort.  That's the entire premise of the question.

Comment: +1 because you admit clearly that readability is more important than performance (at some point) in your opinion.

Comment: @yazanpro: It is trade-off, if performance is really not show stopper, then I would concentrate on readability rather than worrying about small details of code, but in some cases, code is readable, but performance bad because of multiple unnecessary calls, then I would spend time to tune the code till I can balance both performance and readability.

Comment: @Servy thanks for pointing this out, I think I missed the point a bit and updated the code :-)

Comment: I would save the result of `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)` in a variable outside the loop. For the rest it's fine and is readable.